# Can I turn IntInf to String?

Tags: sml

So, I'm writing a program in SML. It works perfectly, but when really large ints are applied, it produces this error:

```
     uncaught exception Overflow [overflow] 
        raised at:Basis/Implementation/num-scan.sml:268.20-268.28
```

What I think is that I should be using the IntInf structure instead of int.
But since in my program I convert ints to Strings and vise versa, how can I turn an IntInf to a String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `IntInf.toString`:

```
$ sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Tue Aug  8 23:21:20 2017]
- IntInf.toString 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890;
[autoloading]
[...]
val it = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890" : string
```

I would actually have thought that this would produce a parse error, since the integer literal is too large to fit a standard 31-bit integer, and that it would have been necessary to `open IntInf` so that the type `int` is overridden by the type `IntInf.int`. But it seems that SML/NJ is flexible this way and that this is apparently not necessary, at least not in the REPL.

You can also construct it from smaller 31-bit integers:

```
- IntInf.pow (IntInf.fromInt 2, 64);
val it = 18446744073709551616 : IntInf.int
```

Here the literals `2` and `64` fit into the functions:

```
- IntInf.fromInt;
val it = fn : int -> IntInf.int

- IntInf.pow;
val it = fn : IntInf.int * int -> IntInf.int
```

So while integer literals are overloaded in SML/NJ so they can mean both an `IntInf` directly, or a 31-bit integer, you can also construct an `IntInf` without referring to such a literal, using purely smaller integers and library functions (so that the `IntInf` is treated more as an abstract type). Not that this is necessary.